# SSH to Linux server: Does port 22 need to be open server side and client side?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, git

Apologies if this is indeed a duplicate; I did look for an answer but it left me with more questions.

I have set up a server, Ubuntu 16.04, to act as a git server for me and one other person to work on a project. Currently, port 22 (Soon I will reconfigure to another port for security) on the server and my firewall are configred correctly and it is open.

In order for a successful connection between the server and client wishing to SSH and clone repos, does the SSH port need to be open server-side *and* the client wishing to connect, or just the server?

My confusion iniitally is because of how TCP works; A configured port for SSH may use one assigned port for the server, and one assigned randomly by the client making the connection?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Changing the SSH port does little for security, a port scanner will find it very quickly anyway. What you need is long and passwords (or just SSH key login), and a firewall that limits the rate at which random people can connect to your server. I recommend that you install `ufw` (UncomplicatedFireWall), and just use `ufw limit` on your SSH port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard setup, the SSH server is listening on port 22, i.e. this port is open for incoming connections. The client opens a connection from a random (high) TCP port (e.g. port 12345) on its side to port 22 on the server side.

So port 22 only needs to be open on server side.

Comment: Thank you. Just as I thought but this confirms it.